Solution to the ODE $y'=2xy(1+y^2)$
In my differential equations class, we are studying separable equations. I'm asked to find the solution to the IVP $y'=2xy(1+y^2)$, $y(0)=2$. My current approach is to divide both sides by $y(1+y^2)$, then integrating using partial fraction decomp on the LHS.
$$
\int{\frac{1}{y(1+y^2)}dy}=\int{2xdx}
$$
$$
\int{(\frac{1}{y}-\frac{y}{y^2+1})dy}=\int{2xdx}
$$
$$
\ln|y|-\frac{1}{2}\ln|y^2+1|=x^2+C
$$
$$
\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^2+1}}=Ce^{x^2}
$$
My professor expects an explicit solution, but I can't figure out how to get $y$ alone on one side. Am I using a bad integration technique or am I missing some final algebraic trick?

Hint: square both sides and then solve for $y^2$.

Begin squaring both sides:
$$\frac{y^2}{y^2+1}=C^2e^{2x^2} $$
now add and subtract $1$ to simplify the LHS:
$$\frac{y^2}{y^2+1}=\frac{y^2+1-1}{y^2+1}=1-\frac1{y^2+1}\implies \frac1{y^2+1}=1-C^2e^{2x^2} $$
Can you take it from here?
